# How do I make a loop for finding elements inside other elements?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a WebBrowser, I'm tying to get text of some elements, that has inner elements. The hierarchy seems like:

```
<tr class="" id="trItem33998" spry:select="selectedRow" spry:hover="hoverRow">

    <td style="cursor:pointer">
        <span>A4 TECH KB-2150D Q-TR MULTIMEDYA USB SİYAH SET</span> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>18</span>
    </td>

    ...
<tr>
```

There are many enumerated rows like this and I need to get all text in span tags in that table. How can I do this using Visual Basic 2013?

**EDIT:** All ids start with trItem

Answer (score 1):

So I won't do this all for you but if you load your xml into a string, here is what can be at the heart of your loop:

```
   Dim StartingPosition As Integer = 0

    While StartingPosition > -1

        StartingPosition = MyXMLString.IndexOf("id=""trItem", StartingPosition)

        If StartingPosition > -1 Then

            ' your code goes here 

            StartingPosition += 1
        End If

    End While
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. i think i couldn't explain it correctly. i'm working on a webbrowser and trying to get html elements.